# Mapping tag needs work

Tags: discussion, tags

The [mapping](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mapping) tag has questions spanning several different definitions of the word *mapping*.  How do you recommend we handle this?

Answer (score 2):

Browsing the just 17 questions using it:

- remove the tag from those already using [mind-mapping](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mind-mapping) (redundant)
- remove the tag from those already using [maps](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maps) (again, redundant)
- check the remaining questions on what it refers to. Pointer: if they have the [gps](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gps), it's something geographical – and we might consider either simply removing the tag, or replacing it with [maps](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maps)
- Having analyzed the remains, come up with a clear tag-wiki-excerpt (and preferably also tag-wiki) on what this tag shall stand for. In case of multiple options, let's discuss whether to split it into multiple tags (have not thoroughly checked, but to give a picture: `geo-mapping` and `mind-mapping` would be such a pair – the latter already exists, and the former might well turn out a synonym to `maps`.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan.

Comment: Then: volunteers, step in and go ahead! :)

Comment: Tag now removed from all *mind-mapping* questions.

Comment: Tag now removed from all *maps* questions.